# How to see if a Flask app is being run on localhost?

Tags: python, localhost, flask

I want my Flask app to have different behaviors when it is being run on localhost and when it is being hosted online. How can I detect from a flask app when it is on localhost and when it is deployed?

Comment: All websites are always running on localhost.  They're on a host, after all.  Do you mean you want different behaviour if the site is accessed via `http://localhost...`?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a development config file and a deployment config file?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to look at [the configuration handling section of the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/), most specifically, [the part on dev / production](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#development-production).  To summarize here, what you want to do is:

- Load a base configuration which you keep in source control with sensible defaults for things which need to have some value.  Anything which *needs* a value should have the value set to what makes sense for *production* not for *development*.
- Load an additional configuration from a path discovered via an environment variable that provides environment-specific settings (e. g. the database URL).

An example in code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_imports
from flask import Flask
import .config  # This is our default configuration

app = Flask(__name__)

# First, set the default configuration
app.config.from_object(config)

# Then, load the environment-specific information
app.config.from_envvar("MYAPP_CONFIG_PATH")

# Setup routes and then ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

See also: The docs for [`Flask.config`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it. The key is comparing the current root url `flask.request.url_root` against a known url value you want to match.

Excerpt taken from github repo https://github.com/nueverest/vue_flask

```
from flask import Flask, request

def is_production():
    """ Determines if app is running on the production server or not.
    Get Current URI.
    Extract root location.
    Compare root location against developer server value 127.0.0.1:5000.
    :return: (bool) True if code is running on the production server, and False otherwise.
    """
    root_url = request.url_root
    developer_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
    return root_url != developer_url
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get this error from using "request.url_root":

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Any ideas why? Googling it, people talk about using request.url_root a lot, but I don't see anyone else getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Fugly, but it does work...

```
import subprocess, shlex

def get_running_flask_processes(port):
    processes = []
    cmd = f"lsof -ti:{port}"
    result = subprocess.run(shlex.split(cmd), capture_output=True, text=True)
    if result.stdout:
        if "\n" in result.stdout:
            processes += result.stdout.split("\n")
            processes = [int(x) for x in processes if x != '']
        else:
            processes += [int(result.stdout)]
    return processes
```